# Median-median inequality

Tags: probability-theory, integral-inequality

An elementary result from Chebyshev's theorem is that the median and mean of a random variable 
do not differ by more than one standard deviation. I'm curious if there is a similar result for comparing medians of different distributions:

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are real random variables with respective medians $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, does the covariance matrix $\sigma_{ij}$ impose an upper bound on $|\mu_1-\mu_2|$?

**Edit:** As noted in the comments, the question as stated definitely has a negative answer. So let me modify it: My initial conception of the problem was that the random variables have some functional relation (in particular, $X_1=X_2^2$). Does this, or some other narrowing of the question, produce a positive claim?

Comment: Did you want $X_1$ and $X_2$ to have mean zero? Otherwise  let $X_1$ be uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$, and $X_2$ uniformly distributed on  $[N-1,N+1]$. Make them independent. The covariance matrix does not involve $N$.

Comment: Please [edit]  the question  to make it more specific, in particular including $X_2=X_1^2$. Having a general *functional relationship* wouldn't help. By the way, italics are made differently in the text here. See [formatting help](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Thanks for italics (I actually entered that comment earlier than I intended---I'm editing it now to make it actually sensible.)

Comment: Here's the comment I intended: Thank you for the nice counterexample under the assumptions I gave. I remain curious whether a different formulation of the problem would work. For instance, when originally thinking of this problem, I had in mind the case of $X_1$ and $X_2$ having some particular functional relation (e.g. $X_1 = X_2^2$). So I remain curious whether there is some class of $(X_1,X_2)$ for which this does work, or a bound arising from something other than the covariance matrix...